# XAMPP: mariadb takes a long time to connect to the port (about 60 sec)

Tags: mysql, xampp, port, delay

I open the XAMPP (7.0.23) Control Panel (v.3.2.2) and start Apache and MySql. Apache connects immediately, but MySql takes a long time to display the port (3306) on the panel and start the connection. I already changed the MySql port for others but it did not work. I've also reinstalled XAMPP twice without success.

Using Win 10.

Follow the log:

> 2017-09-22  8:59:11 9704 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count
>   buffer pool pages
>
> 2017-09-22  8:59:11 9704 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is
>   disabled
>
> 2017-09-22  8:59:11 9704 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use
>   Windows interlocked functions
>
> 2017-09-22  8:59:11 9704 [Note] InnoDB: _mm_lfence() and _mm_sfence()
>   are used for memory barrier
>
> 2017-09-22  8:59:11 9704 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib
>   1.2.3
>
> 2017-09-22  8:59:11 9704 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32
>   instructions
>
> 2017-09-22  8:59:11 9704 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size
>   = 16.0M
>
> 2017-09-22  8:59:11 9704 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of
>   buffer pool
>
> 2017-09-22  8:59:11 9704 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format
>   is Barracuda.
>
> 2017-09-22  8:59:12 9704 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence number
>   1835037 in ibdata file do not match the log sequence number 131851166
>   in the ib_logfiles!
>
> 2017-09-22  8:59:28 9704 [Note] InnoDB: Processed 1298 .ibd/.isl files
>
> 2017-09-22  8:59:35 9704 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible
>   half-written data pages from the doublewrite buffer...
>
> 2017-09-22  8:59:36 9704 [Note] InnoDB: Read redo log up to
>   LSN=131851264
>
> 2017-09-22  9:00:01 9704 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are
>   active.
>
> 2017-09-22  9:00:01 9704 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
>
> 2017-09-22  9:00:01 9704 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB
>   (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.36-82.1 started; log sequence number
>   131851166
>
> 2017-09-22  9:00:01 10900 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not
>   yet started 2017-09-22  9:00:01 9704 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is
>   disabled.
>
> 2017-09-22  9:00:01 9704 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
>
> 2017-09-22  9:00:02 9704 [Note] c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready
>   for connections.
>
> Version: '10.1.26-MariaDB'  socket: ''  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary
>   distribution

Tks.

Comment: Looks like the last shutdown was not clean and the server needs to start recovery at `8:59:12` until `9:00:01`. I Wouldn't worry too much. Does it take as long if you do a clean restart of the service?

Comment: When I stop and then restart the service in the control panel, it takes the same long time to start the service.

Comment: In time: using Win 10